# How to locate dropdown and select values with no id and class name with spaces

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to select a dropdown, and afterwards values inside it, with no id and a class name with spaces. The html I am looking at is

```
<input class="us-form-input us-form-input us-form-input--blocked autocomplete-input__input us-form-select" type="text" placeholder="Search for address" icon="magnify" value="">
<ul class="us-list--rest address-select__address-list">
    <li><button>Address 1</button></li>
    <li><button>Address 2</button></li>
    <li><button>Address 3</button></li>
    <li data-event="true" data-event-category="gas-electricity" data-event-action="supply-address" data-event-label="address-not-listed">
        <button>My address is not listed</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I am new to xpath but thought that classes with spaces in could not be searched. I have tried searching by placeholder and values in the dropdown with no success.

See below for python code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

def page_is_loaded(driver):
    return driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body") != None
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get("https://www.uswitch.com/gas-electricity/")
wait = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(page_is_loaded)
search_form = driver.find_element_by_id('input-postcode')
search_form.send_keys('SW7 2BX')
wait = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Compare energy deals now')]").click()
wait = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name('iframe'))
#driver.find_element_by_css_selector("us-form-input.us-form-input.us-form-input--blocked").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Search for address']").click()
```

Comment: Selenium can look up classes with spaces. You just need to use `"class with space"` as search param, for example.
And you can use `xPath` without an exact ID. You just can name the element related to it´s wrapper or element above. So it can be formed like: `wrapper-div.otherElement.dropdownList`

Comment: @LenglBoy Can you expand on the syntax required? A google search of "selenium 'class with space'" yields nothing.

Comment: You can see the [selenium find documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) which is very helpful. So in the end it can look like this `driver.find_element_by_class_name('class with space')` and you will find it.

Comment: @LenglBoy This does not work -  raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted
  (Session info: chrome=73.0.3683.86)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.46.628402 (536cd7adbad73a3783fdc2cab92ab2ba7ec361e1),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)

Comment: Strange. I´ve searched for class names with spaces etc. and it worked. It was some months ago but it worked. Sry I can´t help you then.

Comment: @LenglBoy Searching for classes with spaces using `find_element_by_class_name()` has never worked. I think you are confusing it with something else, maybe by XPath? It throws `Compound class names not permitted`.

Comment: @JeffC You´re right. I´ve mixed it up with a self-made implementation of `By.ClassNames()` and `By.cssSelector(".X.Y.Z")` where I was able to use multiple classes/params. I prefer the TestIT-Webtester (java). Selenium based, better structure and more features.

Answer (score 1):

As there is an iframe present in the html, you need to first switch to the iframe and then click on the element, you can switch on the iframe like:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name('iframe'))
```

And then you can click on the dropdown menu using the xpath:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Search for address']").click()
```

And then you can select the value like:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='Address 1']").click()
```

**Updated answer after discussion with OP:**

The dropdown values are upfront displayed on the UI and iframe is also not present above its html, so you don't need to click on the dropdown or switch to the iframe, so you just need to use the below line of code and it would work:

```
def page_is_loaded(driver):
    return driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body") != None
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get("https://www.uswitch.com/gas-electricity/")
wait = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(page_is_loaded)
search_form = driver.find_element_by_id('input-postcode')
search_form.send_keys('SW7 2BX')
wait = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Compare energy deals now')]").click()
wait = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 20)   
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//ul[contains(@class,'address-select')]//button)[1]").click()
```

**Code in java:** (After discussion with OP)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path to chromedriver");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.uswitch.com/gas-electricity/");
    driver.findElement(By.id("input-postcode")).click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.id("input-postcode")).sendKeys("SW7 2BX");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Compare energy deals now')]")).click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Imperial College, Department Of Mechanical Engineering, Exhibition Road, London, SW7 2BX']")).click();
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging sessions; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191037/discussion-on-answer-by-sameer-arora-how-to-locate-dropdown-and-select-values-wi). Please make sure to [edit] the answer to include all relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

you can try below code:-

use xpath for drop down list element.

selenium provides [select class](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#filling-in-forms)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('url')

driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath_of_dropdownlist").click()

select_Add = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("Address 1"))

select_Add.select_by_index(0)
```

for more information see [this](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1355/what-is-the-correct-way-to-select-an-option-using-seleniums-python-webdriver) link.

Comment: My question is what is the xpath of the dropdown list if there is no id and the class has spaces in it, see updated question for url and python code used.